# Approach for writing a composite health endpoint for spring boot based microservices

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-boot-actuator

I am working on a scenarios where, we need to have a composite health actuator for our service. For e.g. we have 3 services A,B & C. Health of "Service A" is dependent on "Service B" and that of "Service B" is dependent on "Service C". So if either of services is down or unhealthy, health check for Services A should fail.

We can do that by making a simple webclient (HTTP) call for the health endpoint and check the status. But wanted to check, if there is any other efficient approach for same as the SLA for health endpoint should be less then 1 sec or as minimal as possible.

We are using PCF as PaaS.Any thoughts/suggestions on the same.

Thanks,
Sagar

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar using http, through the RestTemplate to do health checks and dint face any delay, it fairly responds well.

If you can use Internal routes (*.apps.internal i.e. container to container) then it could be more efficient as traffic will stay within PCF.

Comment: Thanks @arjain13 for the reply. Are you using all the health indicators in the health check or just using the downstream health indicators ? Also we don't have any explicit internal routes defined, but I think that worth exploring.

Comment: Hi @sagar27, We are not ausing DB all the indicators - just few + downstream health.